# How can I unit test a function that validates a datetime is in a specific ISO format?

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime

I'm new to unit testing and I would like some guidance on this topic. The function validates if a datetime is a string first and if so then validates if it is in the right ISO format.

```
if not isinstance(timestamp,str):
    raise ValueError("timestamp must be a string")
try:
    datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return True
except ValueError:
    return True
```

How can I determine what to include in my unit test and what should I be on the lookout for?

Comment: For one thing, I don't see any way for this function to return `False`.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to come up with edge cases. Which relies a lot on experience with the problem domain—what bugs have you seen dealing with datetimes in the past. But fortunately, you can always just add more unit tests as you find and fix bugs or think of odd cases while waiting for a Lyft or whatever.

There are some particular things to watch out for with datetimes—but note that many of them, you first have to decide what you want to do, before you can test whether you're doing what you decided to do.

- Make sure non-strings raise a `ValueError`, of course. Including `bytes`.
- Single-digit days and months—is `2018-3-06` a valid date?
- Likewise for hours, minutes, and seconds (but sometimes the rule you want is different).
- Different separators—e.g., `2018-03-06 12:13:14` is a valid ISO timestamp, but not valid by your rule. Same with, for that matter, `20180306T12:13:14`, and many other variations.
- All of the obvious past-the-end values, like month 0 or 13—but see below for the odd exceptions, like second 60.
- Timestamps too far in the past for other parts of your code to handle. For example, ISO allows dates in 1960, but if your code is going to pass them to an API that deals with uint32 Unix timestamps, they're not valid as far as you're concerned.
- Year 0000. According to ISO 8601, this means 1 BCE, but you may not want that.
- Two-digit years. And one-, three-, and five-digit years. And negative years, and years with an explicit `+` prefix. ISO 8601 recommends four-digit years like 0030, but also recommends allowing `+` and `-` prefixes (and that's the only way to handle years before 1 BCE), and allows years like 10010 "by usually agreement of the partners in information interchange.
- Fractional seconds. Someone will pass you `2018-06-20T15:16:17.890`.
- Time zone/offset indicators. Someone will pass you `2018-06-20T15:16:17Z`.
- 29 Feb on leap years (including 2000) and non-leap-years (including 1900).
- Leap seconds—e.g., `2005-12-31T23:59:60` UTC or `2006-01-01T08:59:60` local in Japan.
- Hours that don't exist because of DST changeover, if you're dealing with local times—e.g., `2018-03-11T02:30:00` does not exist in most of the USA.
- Days that don't exist because of calendar changeover, if you're dealing with local times and care about the past—e.g., the missing 11 days in UK 1752, 13 days in Russia 1918, etc.

Comment: of course for most of these tests, it would actually be testing the underlying datetime library which has tests of its own. Maybe there is a subset of that which would be enough to check the code actually implemented in this function?

Comment: @jsbueno If your desired behavior is “whatever the Python `datetime` library does is right” (which it often is for quick&dirty scripts, or for serious libraries meant to work closely with the stdlib in a wide range of apps), you don’t  need to test much. But if your goal is “handle this input”, then you need to test everything. If something fails because the library has a bug, or because it wasn’t designed to do what you wanted it to but you didn’t realize that, or whatever, it’s still a failure, and you still have to decide how to deal with it. So you should unit test it.

Comment: @jsbueno All that being said, most of your code isn’t going to be a trivial wrapper around a stdlib function in the first place… And when it _is_, it probably is a good idea to grub through the stdlib unit tests and make sure the behavior they’re testing is actually the behavior you want, even if you aren’t going to just copy or use them.